# Table only displays on occasions

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

First post on Stackoverflow, **be gentle**. 
Since I think my error lies somewhere in the logic and haven't found any similar questions I decided to go forward with it.

**Situation as follows:**

*I have a global empty array called redirects.*

```
var redirects = [];
```

*redirects[] fills dynamically based on ajax response data*

```
function ajaxFunction() {
within success call:
    var prefix = "abc";
    for (var key in data) {
        var url = (prefix + key);
        redirects[key.toLowerCase()] = url;
        }
}
```

*In my on-click method I bind the clicked class to it's url and call the function that creates a table; followed by the one that dynamically fills it based on our url.*

```
/**
 * Bind clicked class to url and call function to fill table.
 */

$(myid).on("click", "a", function () {

    // Get the clicked class selector.
    var clicked = $(this.getAttribute("class"));
    var selectedClass = clicked.selector;

    // Check for same value and break operation when found.
    for(var key in redirects) {
        if (key == selectedClass) {

            // Set the url to redirect in fillTable function.
            var url = redirects[key];
            break;
        }
    }

    // Returns values as we expect
    // console.log(key, " | ", url);

    // Construct a table based on url.
    table();
    fillTable(url);
});
```

FYI: table() displays a table form in html; fillTable() fills the th & td;
Both functions work fine with static url immediately defined but I want it dynamically based on the click.

Now, when I test this out, this only works when spamming the link quickly instead of just clicking it once.

This leads me to believe that the reason for it not showing up immediately, is because somehow the for-loop within my on-click is still running and requires the second click to be recorded (but I'm just guessing here).

Comment: When is the ajax function called? I would guess that when you click your `redirects` variable is still empty.

Comment: The ajax function which fills the `redirects` array is called when the page loads. It is within a similar function named `navigation()` and `fillNavigation()`. Those are working fine since they use the whole db.json file to find and fill the collections within the navigation. Whilst creating them I reference their css classes as a key and their url as a value.

Comment: Well, then maybe it's still not finished when you click on the link. You can check it, maybe put a console.log("ajax done") in the success callback and see if you're just clicking too early.

Comment: [link]https://gyazo.com/5cd5057b0db245dd95fbb7e8b864f886 I have tried what you said but it gets called immediately.

Comment: Look, it's not very clear from the video and the code you posted, but it seems to me that both the ajax call and the table construction happen after you click on that link. The ajax call might get called immediately, but it will very often finish later. I think you should call the table-building functions in the ajax callback.

Comment: [link](https://gyazo.com/0bbbb4e25b7627117f68b8e8bbca1405) Found the issue. It was as simple as a stupid preventDefault that I forgot to use on the click event. Which is why the event kept on bubbling up through the DOM. All works fine, thx for the effort !